# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10c111c68) to subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to build a fairly straight forward table of data, and am following along with this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

I have the following custom cell class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WorkItemCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and the following function in my TableClass:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkItemCell") as! WorkItemCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.work[indexPath.row]["name"] as! String
    return cell
}
```

This results in:

`Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10c111c68) to 'proj.WorkItemCell' (0x10a84c4c0).`

Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You _have_ a custom cell class. But please explain why you expect `self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to return an instance _of that class_. I don't see you doing anything that would cause that to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, what I realized the problem was is that I was using `UITableViewCell.self` in my `tableView.registerClass`, changing that to `WorkItemCell.self` fixed the problem

Comment: Hi. Could you please show that whole line...am getting the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your idenrifier for the custom class is WorkItemCell and also you need to register the nib in viewdidload like

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "WorkItemCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "WorkItemCell")
```

and your cell code like .

```
var cell:WorkItemCell= self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkItemCell") as! WorkItemCell
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/abraham/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/067351E6-EB79-451A-8929-2098AE421DF7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6204880F-862F-4C8F-87AA-6561B2709DEC/gucci.app> (loaded)' with name 'WorkItemCell''

Comment: do you have xib for the cell ? If yes double check the name